# Arduino MKR Vidor 4000

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, camera

Can it capture the image in full Rpi camera resolution and save it somewhere?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does the data sheet(s) of the devices tell you?

Comment: W'ah? or in other words: huh?

Comment: Its a new board, it doesnt have much info on it. It only says it has high speed DPS and MIPI camera. I know it has very powerful CPU on it, it should be capable, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Raspberry Pi camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ER2SKFS) is an 8-megapixel sensor.

The [Arduino MKR Vidor 4000](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14870) has 8 MB of on-board SRAM.

So the answer is no, with only 8 bits per pixel, the board cannot store an uncompressed image from the camera. It would normally require 2× (YUV 4:2:2) to 3× (RGB 4:4:4) that amount of memory. The best you could do would be to store a "raw" (Bayer-encoded) 8-bit image for post-processing elsewhere.

BTW, while the board does contain a relatively powerful SAM D Cortex-M0+ based microcontroller, the primary feature that gives it its real power is the FPGA — this is going to require knowledge of hardware design (and HDL) in order to make use of it.

What are you trying to do? For most applications, it would be easier (and cheaper) to plug the camera into an actual RPi.